# Is GAIL applicable if the expert's trajectories are for the same task but are in a different environment?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, generative-adversarial-networks, generative-model, imitation-learning, gail

Is the [GAIL](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2016/file/cc7e2b878868cbae992d1fb743995d8f-Paper.pdf) applicable if the expert's trajectories (sample data) are for the same task but are in a different environment (modified but will not be completely different)?

My gut feeling is, yes, otherwise we can just simply adopt behavioural cloning. Furthermore, since the expert's trajectories are from a different environment, the dimension/length of state-action pairs will most likely be different. Will those trajectories still be useful for GAIL training?

Comment: What do you mean by "behavioural cloning" here?

Comment: I mean the supervised imitation learning approach where the agent tries to copy the demonstrated labeled data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authors of the paper [Learning Robust Rewards with Adversarial Inverse Reinforcement Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.11248.pdf) (2018, published in ICRL), which introduced the inverse RL technique **AIRL**, argue that **GAIL** fails to generalize to different environment's dynamics. Specifically, in section 7.2 (p. 7), they describe an experiment where they disable and shrink the two front legs of the [ant](https://gym.openai.com/envs/Ant-v2/), then, based on the results, they conclude

> GAIL learns successfully in the training domain, but does not acquire a representation that is suitable for transfer to test domains.

On the other hand, according to their experiments, AIRL is more robust to changes in the environment's dynamics.